# Is there a way to get the state to update at the right time?

Tags: reactjs, fetch

I successfully send a post request, and the entry enters the database. I want the app to re-render to show the new entry in the table. However the setState hits on the addForm Variable and the form vanishes but it does not re-render again to show the new character, I know this is due to asynchronicity, just unsure on how to make that work in the right order.

So far I have attempted: 
- to make sure the promise is returned - no change in behaviour

- adding a third .then to setState again to try and force a re-render - no change in behaviour
- tried forcing with this.forceUpdate - no change in behaviour
- All research shows setState as the way to fix this but having no success. I now wonder if my syntax is wrong or poorly constructed.

The Fetch request

```
  handleSubmit = (character) => {
    console.log(character);
    const url = "http://localhost:3000//api/v1/basics"
    const body = JSON.stringify(
     { name: character.name,
       age: character.age,
       sex: character.sex,
       classs: character.classs,
       race: character.race,
       height: character.height
     })
     fetch(url,{
       method: 'POST',
       headers:{
         'Content-Type': 'application/json'
       },
       body: body
     }).then((res) =>{
       return res.json();
     }).then((res) => {
       this.setState({ character: res })
     }).then((res) => {
       console.log(this.state);
       this.setState({ addForm: false })
     })
}
```

I am expecting the component to re-render with the new entry but no re-render happens after the form closes. If i refresh the page then it updates but not onclick.

EDIT 1. : FUlly component, I know its a mess this is a play with react and see what it does program.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Table from './Table'
import SimpleCharacterInfoForm from './SimpleCharacterForm'
import CharacterSkillsForm from './characterSkillsForm'
import './App.css'

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    addForm: false,
    editForm: false,
    character: []
  }



  addCharacter = () => {
    this.setState({
      addForm: true
    })
  }

  removeCharacter = index => {

    const url = `http://localhost:3000//api/v1/basics/${index}`

    fetch(url,{
      method: 'DELETE'
  }).then((res) => {
    res.json()
  }).then((res) => {
    this.setState({})
  })
}

  handleSubmit = (character) => {
    console.log(character);
    const url = "http://localhost:3000//api/v1/basics"
    const body = JSON.stringify(
     { name: character.name,
       age: character.age,
       sex: character.sex,
       classs: character.classs,
       race: character.race,
       height: character.height
     })
     fetch(url,{
       method: 'POST',
       headers:{
         'Content-Type': 'application/json'
       },
       body: body
     }).then((res) =>{
       return res.json();
     }).then((res) => {
       this.setState({ addForm: false })
     })
}

    render() {
      const {characters, addForm, editForm, character} = this.state;
      let render = ''
      if (addForm === true){
          render = this.renderAddCharacter(characters)
        } else if (editForm === true) {
          render = this.renderEditCharacterSKills(character)
        } else {
          render = this.renderWithOutForms(characters)
        }
    return render
    }

    renderAddCharacter(characters){
      return(
        <div className="characterTable">
            <Table
              characterData={characters}
              removeCharacter={this.removeCharacter}
              editCharacter={this.editCharacter}
           />
             < SimpleCharacterInfoForm
                handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
            />
          <button onClick={this.addCharacter}>Add Character</button>
        </div>
      )
    }

    renderEditCharacterSKills(character){
      return(
        <div className="characterSkillsForm">
          <CharacterSkillsForm
            handleEdit={this.handleEdit}
            character={character}/>
        </div>
      )
    }

    renderWithOutForms(characters){
      return(
        <div className="characterTable">
            <Table
              characterData={characters}
              removeCharacter = {this.removeCharacter}
              editCharacter={this.editCharacter}
           />
          <button onClick={this.addCharacter}>Add Character</button>
        </div>
      )
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the fetch happening in the same Component as the one showing the entries? - If its a parent component, you could pass a callback prop and call it when the data is ready, so  the parent will be able to setState on its own..

Comment: Can you post your `render() { ... }` code?

Comment: show your whole component

Comment: @LucianoSemerini the fetch request to populate the table happens in a child component of App, called Table. In Table there is the fetch request that gets the data.